# Is there a significant performance difference between $first and $last in MongoDB's $group aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm using MongoDB's aggregation framework on a collection where each document has an array of zero or more "tags". A tag can occur on one or more documents, but for my purposes, a tag that is only used on one document is useless. To find the tags that occur only once, and the documents that those tags belong to, I can do:

```
db.docs.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$tags"},
    {$group: {_id: "$tags", count: {$sum: 1}, docId: {$last: "$_id"}}},
    {$match: {count: 1}}])
```

But since I only care about tags that occur once, the first document is the same as the last document, so I would get the same results with:

```
db.docs.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$tags"},
    {$group: {_id: "$tags", count: {$sum: 1}, docId: {$first: "$_id"}}}, 
    {$match: {count: 1}}])
```

So is there a significant performance difference between using $first or $last with the aggregation framework? Intuitively, it seems like they should both be quick ($first should check if the result exists, and only write to it if it doesn't; $last should just overwrite whatever is there each time), but I've been burned in the past with things that I thought were equivalent.

Comment: The two code samples you posted appear to be identical. Also, please try to format them in a more readable way.